# Edit a Redirected Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wp-admin

I've built a wordpress site for a client, but they needed the site temporarily redirected to a different domain. I added the line `redirect 302 / https://www.temporary_domain.com` to the .htaccess file. The issue is that while the site is under redirect, I still need to be able to work on the live, original site, by signing into www.original_domain.com/wp-admin. Is there any way I can do this without removing the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as a beginner, you would like to go easy and without coding. If you, then follow up. First of all, install and activate the [**Simple Website Redirect**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-website-redirect/) plugin from **Plugins > Add New**.

The Simple Website Redirect plugin allows to you redirect an entire website (except the WordPress admin) to another website.

The URL path and query string are preserved when redirecting to the new site. Ideally, the new site would handle any one-off redirects where a URL for an old page should point to a new page. The [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin is great for this purpose if you have a big site.

*Note: If you want to redirect only the homepage to another site, then Redirection plugin can be the simple and best solution for you.*

Using the plugin is simple. Head over to **Settings > Website Redirect**, enter the URL you want to redirect the site to, set the desired redirection type, set the status to ‘Enabled’ and save your changes.

[image: Simple Website Redirect Screenshot]

I hope the above method worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following! Change the 00.00.00.00 to your IP and the example.com to the actual site you want to redirect to. This should redirect everyone but you base on your Ip address.

```
# Redirect other IP addresses
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^00.00.00.00
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WordPress filter [admin_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_url/) to access wp-admin without changing the address from database when user original_domain.com

```
apply_filters( 'admin_url', string $url, string $path, int|null $blog_id );
```

and use htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp-admin
RewriteRule (.*) newdomain.com/$1 [L]
```